# Converting a number of months to date string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number of months.

I wish to represent them as a number of years and months in the format YYMM

e.g.

```
5 -> 0005
13 -> 0101
24 -> 0200
```

Does anyone know of a non-convoluted way to do this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: there is a missing piece of information:  what is the start point in time of the number of months?  How about a table description too...

Comment: You mean you want to divide by twelve and take the result and the remainder. Check the Oracle REMAINDER function.

Comment: I think you need a combination of `floor` and `mod`. Then you could play around with the **format mask**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of maths and some formatting are the way to go:

```
with sample_data as (select 5 num from dual union all
                     select 13 num from dual union all
                     select 24 num from dual union all
                     select 1400 num from dual)
select to_char(floor(num/12), 'fm9999909')||to_char(mod(num, 12), 'fm09') yrmn
from   sample_data;

YRMN       
-----------
0005       
0101       
0200       
11608
```

I included one that had more than 100 years just to show you how it might look; I don't know if that's a possibility in your case, or if you'd want the other values to be zero-padded since you didn't say.

Comment: Exactly what I had in my mind. Just the format mask could be left to OP's jurisdiction ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select lpad(trunc(yourValue/12),2,'0')||lpad(mod(yourValue,12),2,'0') result
  from dual
```

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
select right("0" + convert(varchar(20), convert(numeric(10,0), 37/12)), 2)
                 + right("0" + convert(varchar(20), 37%12), 2)

0301
```

I used "37" for example.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the oracle, but it will work on mssql or sybase :)